# Mount point [UUID] does not exist (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, boot, mount, raid, fstab

I have an Ubuntu desktop with 1xSSD with the system installed (/dev/sda) and 4xHDDs running in softraid (/dev/md0, sd[b-e]).
Currently whenever I power on my PC, Ubuntu initially fails to boot, saying:

```
Mount point bcb7c4d3-574e-43f0-9f73-658ab99652c4 does not exist
```

If I press S to boot anyway, the system boots fine, and while the raid array doesn't automatically boot (even though its configured to), I can manually mount it in `Disks`.

This is my `/etc/fstab/` file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name     devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type> <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=454daf70-785f-4887-aa02-8998e0ae819b /               ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=346b9234-0246-40cf-a7f1-bd630ad178dc none            swap sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/bcb7c4d3-574e-43f0-9f73-658ab99652c4 /mnt/bcb7c4d3-574e-43f0-9f73-658ab99652c4 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

When it comes to editing fstab, I have no idea what I'm doing and thought best to ask here before going to town on it.

This is the output of `fdisk -l':

```
root@MAXWELL:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006d15a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   100489215    50243584   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       100491262   117229567     8369153    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       100491264   117229567     8369152   82  Linux swap / Solaris

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
78 heads, 63 sectors/track, 397542 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux RAID autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 2000.1 GB, 2000138797056 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 488315136 cylinders, total 3906521088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa9013bed

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux RAID autodetect

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
78 heads, 63 sectors/track, 397542 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x51fcb56a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux RAID autodetect

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sde: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
78 heads, 63 sectors/track, 397542 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x51fcb56a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux RAID autodetect
```

Can someone please help me get booting/mounting working properly?

Edit: blkid output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="454daf70-785f-4887-aa02-8998e0ae819b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="346b9234-0246-40cf-a7f1-bd630ad178dc" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="3e05ec7a-7639-ede0-f10a-479bb9aa5f56" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0: LABEL="apps" UUID="f9e0cb41-0eec-4711-849b-b6264496e7be" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="e5dd8df4-1984-9909-9dd0-c27944b24ccc" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="5147b7a9-ff6f-8fd0-0a67-f5be2c6d2ae2" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sde1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="814353c9-6b9e-621d-0f13-d05845264b33" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
```

Comment: Can you edit the output of `sudo blkid` into your post so we can see the UUIDs?

Comment: I see no reference in `sudo blkid` to the uuid that is in the last line of your fstab. What happens if you comment out that line and reboot? Caveat: I am unfamiliar with RAID setups.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. I'll post it as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by following Organic Marble's advice, and commenting out the line:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/bcb7c4d3-574e-43f0-9f73-658ab99652c4 /mnt/bcb7c4d3-574e-43f0-9f73-658ab99652c4 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

from `/etc/fstab` and rebooting. The system now boots normally, and the raid array mounts automatically just fine.